# Order of infinitesimal of inverse function

Tags: calculus

Say $f$ and $h$ are injective functions $(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ that both tend to $0$ as $x\to0$. Let $\alpha>0$. If 
$$f(x)=h(x)+\omicron(x^\alpha)\,,\;\;x\to0$$
can I say that
$$f^{-1}(y)=h^{-1}(y)+\omicron(y^{\beta})\,,\;\;y\to0$$
for some $\beta$, where $f^{-1}$, $h^{-1}$ are the inverses (of the obvious restrictions)? If yes, which $\beta$? If not, how should I fix this?

Comment: No, this result can not be correct. You can easily verify this by taking a simple example, such as h(x) = x and alfa = 2.

Comment: Yep, I'd realized this in the meanwhile. Now wondering if the edited question is still naive or not...

Comment: I don't regard your question as naive. You want to know how the presence of a small extra term in an equation influences taking the inverse of a function. That is a good question, which can be answered mathematically. And the result is far from obvious. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write your expression in a slightly different form:

$$y = f(x) + C*g(x)$$

where, in the region of interest, the first term is much larger than the second term. To emphasize this I have introduced a parameter $C$, which is sufficiently small, say $0.001$. Now in lowest order approximation we can simply ignore the second term. Solving the equation yields:

$$x = inv(f(y))$$

Where $inv$ stands for inverse. We construct a first order solution by adding a second term to this which is linear in $C$. We then substitute the expression in the original equation, use a Taylor expansion and combine the resulting terms. This way we find:

$$x = inv(f(y)) - C * g(inv(f(y)) / f'(inv(f(y))$$

It is possible to construct higher order approximations (in terms of the parameter $C$) by adding extra terms to the last expression and repeating the above described procedure. However it should be expected that these higher order terms turn out to be rather messy.

Comment: The problem with using Taylor expansions (as in your last paragraph) is that $f(x)$,$h(x)$ (resp. $y(x)$ and $f(x)$ in your notation) are not assumed to be continuous in $x$. But it's nevertheless a useful answer in the case of smooth functions (and maybe for other asymptotic expansions).

Comment: A question: should your last equation be understood as a first-order (in $C$) approximation of $x(y)$ rather than an exact equality? I mean, shouldn't a term of the form $\phi(y,C)$ be added to the RHS, with $\phi(y,C)=\omicron(C)$ for $C\to 0$, or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I certainly regard the last equation in my answer as a first-order Taylor series approximation in the small parameter $C$. And since it is an approximation, you are free to make it "exact" by adding a term, say $o(C^2)$.

Comment: Can the argument be somehow extended to the case $f,h$ not continuous?

Comment: I am not so certain about this ! But I would assume that as long as the relation between $x$ and $y$ is 1-on-1 (so that an inverse function can be defined), and as long as the domain is piecewise continuous (so that at every point derivatives of the function exist) the procedure works fine.